# What's causing my VM's OS to hang on "Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies"?

Tags: linux, boot, vmware-fusion, yocto-project

I have generated an OS using the Yocto Project, with Linux kernel version 3.14. I have tried several methods to boot this OS from VMware Fusion, all with seemingly-identical results, where the process hangs after `Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies`. I have removed the VM's USB controller. Here's the relevant part of the message log that I see:

```
Waiting for root device /dev/hda2...
Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 863336102 ns)
Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried disabling time syncing between Host and Guest? See: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1189

Comment: just tried your suggestion with no apparent changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was so focused on the two lines about clocksources that I missed the crucial line: `Waiting for root device /dev/hda2...`; my hard drive was not being recognized because my OS image was configured to use IDE. Within VMware Fusion I had missed that my HD bus type was configured to SCSI.  I was able to fix this by navigating to `VM settings->Startup Disk->Advanced options->Bus type`, and set to IDE.